# Extracting the exact word between two words without question mark in python using REGEX

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to extract a word between two specific words in a string.

Here is what I have tried so far,

```
import re
st = 'did this something?Yessomething'
re.findall('did this something?(.*?)something', st)
```

```
Current Output: ['?Yes']
```

```
Desired Output: ['Yes']
```

I can replace the question mark with a blank space to get the desired output but I am looking for the way to extract the exact word after the question mark and the next word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `?` after `something`.

Do it as follows:

```
print(re.findall('did this something\\?(.*?)something', st))
```

**Output:**

```
['Yes']
```